# Scroll bars never appear when re-sizing web page

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

so I made a website but for some reason no matter what I do, I cannot get any scrollbars to appear when the page is too small. I've been looking for quite some time but can't find a solution. I've tried many things but can't figure it out for the life of me. I suspect it has something to do with overflow but even adjusting that doesn't seem to work. If anybody could help me diagnose this, I'd really appreciate it. I'll go ahead and link the relevant codes below. I know it's probably a simple problem, but I'm about to rip my hair out trying to figure it out. Thank you for any help, I really appreciate it.

Main index page: http://pastebin.com/TkdzdKbG

CSS Style: http://pastebin.com/tMKQtC6v

Comment: The website is http://theromdepot.com/ if anybody wants to see the problem for themselves.

Comment: you have javascript error, you can use jquery(selectors, functions and etc) when the jquery library is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply this CSS

```
.ibg-bg {
    height: 100% !important;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Remove position

```
.bg {
    height: 100%;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow! This did it! Thank you so much. And thank you to Kanchan and Ryubro for helping out too. You guys are the best.

Comment: One last question. How can I remove the bottom scroll bar? I tried overflow-x: hidden; but it still appears.

Comment: Could you please tell me why there is now a white line at the bottom of the screen when your mouse gets close? It's harder to see on the main page, but you can really see the problem here: http://theromdepot.com/emulators.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the solution you're looking for but in your "container" div, there's an inline style "overflow:hidden", if you remove that, you can get scrollbars whenever the page is too small.

http://prntscr.com/8pcd0f

Comment: Interesting. When I removed it, it showed the scroll bars but instead caused this to happen when resizing the page: http://box.endurehosting.com/contents/private/96.35.205.122/8758c562-23c0-4218-b62a-95f9daffa443.jpg

Comment: Try giving your ".bg" div a height of 100vh.

.bg{
height:100vh /*vh instead of %*/
}

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of overflow property. Try this on your stylesheet,

```
.container .bg {
   overflow:scroll !important;
}
```

Comment: The same issue happened as Kanchan's solution. I've adjusted the page to your answer and you can see it's now doing this when resizing:

http://box.endurehosting.com/contents/private/96.35.205.122/8758c562-23c0-4218-b62a-95f9daffa443.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Most of your contents are under `div.bg > div.display` but the height of the parent node-`div.bg`- is 100% and its `overflow` value is set `hidden` by one of the scripts. (`query.interactive_bg.js`, I guess)

You can set the height of `div.display` to 100% and its `overflow-y` value to `scroll` to scroll the contents or if you want a horizontal scroll bar as well, change `overflow-y` to `overflow`.

Add these line to your `style.css` file, line 172:

```
.display{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;       /* Added */
  overflow-y: scroll; /* Added */
}
```

Comment: I think @Lalji Tadhani 's solution is better than mine.